# How to convert an array to a two dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'd like to convert this array:

```
Array
(
    [5] => 3.5
    [6] => 4.5
    [7] => 5.5

)
Array
(
    [8] => 5
    [9] => 6
    [10] => 7

)
```

Into a two-dimensional array that would look like this:

```
$array = array(
"a" => array("3.5","4.5", etc.),
"b" => array("5","6", etc.),
);
```

I think I'm getting close with the following code, but I'm still missing a name such as "a" and "b" for each array group:

```
$array = array($result);
echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_chunk($array,2, true));
echo '</pre>';
```

Here is the code from where I'm getting the two arrays :

```
$period = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15);
$sma = array(6,9);

foreach ($sma as $range)    {

    $sum = array_sum(array_slice($period, 0, $range));
    $result = array($range - 1 => $sum / $range);

    for ($i = $range, $n = count($period); $i != $n; ++$i) {

        $result[$i] = $result[$i - 1] + ($period[$i] - $period[$i - $range]) / $range;

    }

    $array = array($result);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(array_chunk($array,2, true));
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: You just did it didn't you!?

Comment: PS: That looks like 2 arrays

Comment: `$array = array("a" => $firstArray, "b" => $secondArray);` Simple

Comment: Agree with @RiggsFolly, with addition of `array_values()` (seems to want to loose keys in final array).

Comment: Ah @Syscall makes a good point

Comment: You had better show us a `print_r($result)` so we know what we are dealing with here. Note- edit that into your question - DONT post as a comment

Comment: What should the keys of the result be if there are more than 26 arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $period = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15);

    $sma = array(6,9);

    $array = array();

    foreach ($sma as $range)    {

    $sum = array_sum(array_slice($period, 0, $range));

    $result = array($range - 1 => $sum / $range);

    for ($i = $range, $n = count($period); $i != $n; ++$i) {

    $result[$i] = $result[$i - 1] + ($period[$i] - $period[$i - $range]) / $range;

    }

//add each array to final array
    $array[] = $result;

    } 
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($array);
    echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.